# Subclassing or exentending djangcms plugin

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, subclassing, extending

I use the cascade bootstrap plugin and like it very much. Now i need to add additional classes to the rows and columnes for styling it more precisely via css. I would like to add style or id -fields to the cascade plugin. I thought the simpliest way is subclassing the cascade plugin but I cant find any way for doing this and I dont find the right place in the docs. Maybe you can give me a hint or point me in the right direction.This is my first djangocms project, I moved from zope.

Any tip or help is appreciated!

Regards,
Klaus

Answer (score 0):

The CSS files that need to be overwritten are in `static/css` for whatever framework (Bootstrap/Grid System 960) that you want to use.  I suggest creating a custom file and including it after the vendor CSS files, leaving them as-is, and have yours overwrite theirs.

See their [documentation](http://djangocms-cascade.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial-bs3.html). In case the link changes: http://djangocms-cascade.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial-bs3.html

They maintain Bootstrap's typical classes for structures, you could probably include a theme from [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/)